# Tkinter Toplevel inf different file/function

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

I am trying to create a Toplevel window, however, this Toplevel is called from a different file in the same directory within a function.

Apologies I am by no means a tkinter or python guru. Here are the two parts of the code. (snippets)

#File 1 (Main)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import comm1
from comm1 import com1

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("")
root.geometry("1900x1314")

#grid Center && 3x6 configuration for correct gui layout
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(11, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(11, weight=1)

#background image
canvas = Canvas(root, width=1900, height=1314)
canvas.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
bckground = PhotoImage(file='img.png')
canvas.create_image(20 ,20 ,anchor=NW, image=bckground)

#command to create new Toplevel
btn1 = tk.Button(root, text='Top', command=com1, justify='center', font=("Arial", 10))
btn1.config(anchor=CENTER)
btn1.grid(row=4, column=1)
```

#File 2 (Toplevel)

```
#command for new window
def com1():
    newWindow1 = Toplevel(root)
    newWindow1.title("")
    newWindow1.geometry("500x500")
    entry1 = tk.Entry(root, justify='center' , font=("Arial", 12), fg="Grey")
    newWindow1.pack()
    newWindow1.mainloop()
```

The weird part is this worked perfectly for a few minutes and without changing any code it just stopped working.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `newWindow1.pack()` should be `entry1.pack()`.

Comment: I think that you should pass in the `root` when calling the function because right now `root` isn't defined. Also instead of `entry1 = tk.Entry(root, ...)` use `entry1 = tk.Entry(newWindow1, ...)`

Comment: oh snap, thank you for the feedback! yeah that is definitely a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `root` as an argument to `com1`

Also, you only need to start `mainloop` once, and that should probably be in the main file. You do not need to call it each time you create a new window.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone that answered,
Decided to bypass the problem with better structuring in a single file. :)